# error with npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, web3js, truffle

I'm running Bash on Windows, and am having a hard time installing any Ethereum related packages (web3, truffle, truffle-hdwallet-provider, etc). From the error log there seems to be multiple errors going on. I tried googling "gyp ERR! build error" and I got it to work once by removing ".node-gyp" in /home/username directory. For some reason this doesn't work anymore....also getting "configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" and have no clue what that means.....

```
> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
configure: error: in `/mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/scrypt/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details


> keccak@1.4.0 install /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/keccak
> npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."


> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/keccak
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nerdyckc/.npm/_logs/2018-09-02T11_56_27_892Z-debug.log
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.

> scrypt@6.0.3 install /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/windf/Documents/bootcamp/capstone/petShop/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.6 requires a peer of truffle@4.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN pet-shop@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN pet-shop@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nerdyckc/.npm/_logs/2018-09-02T11_56_31_324Z-debug.log
```